# Why piping find and grep returns nothing?

Tags: grep, find, pipe

I'm trying to have `grep` search inside specified files that are returned by `find`:

```
find . -type d -name 'mydir*' -exec find '{}' -name '*.java' \; | grep 'MyClass'
```

This doesn't work.

Meanwhile, this works.

```
grep 'MyClass' $(find . -type d -name 'mydir*' -exec find '{}' -name '*.java' \;)
```

What's the problem with my first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In first case you grep the list of filenames returned by `find`, whereas in the second case the filename list is an argument to grep, so grep will search inside the files.

Pipe is a standard input, not a named file. That's why grep behaves differently.
From `man grep`:

> grep  searches  the  named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first case `grep` tries fo find 'MyClass' in filenames and in the second one it tries to find 'MyClass' in file contents.

The first one is equal to

```
find . -type d -name 'mydir*' -exec find '{}' -name '*MyClass*.java' \;
```

while the second one is equal to

```
find . -type d -name 'mydir*' -exec sh -c \
"find '{}' -name '*.java' -exec grep 'MyClass' {} \;" \;
```

Comment: Are you saying that by using pipes i'm feeding grep with stream, so it treats it as a text to search in rather than file names?

Comment: @gasan Yes, if you pipe data into grep it searches it as text, it doesn't treat it as filenames. I think you're looking to stick `xargs` in the pipe

Answer (score 3):

I think your `find` command should be:

```
find . -type f -path 'mydir*.java'| xargs grep -H 'MyClass'
```

Which finds files in `mydir` with `.java` extension and containing *MyClass*. `-H` instructs `grep` to output filename in front of result.

Comment: very helpful, exactly what I was looking for, much better than with $() arguments